# How to fill in select form identifiers with data from an array - Node.js, EJS, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am currently working on creating a form where users can view information from the SQL database and update if necessary. I am able to fill in the data for the `text` form groups, but the `select` form groups are not filling in. The data is coming from an SQL query that is passed from my routes.js file. Here is the code for the form:

```
<div class="well">
    <form action="/addMapRoom/<%= communityMap[0].mapID %>/<%= mapRoom %>" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Room Number</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="roomNumber" value="<%=communityMapData[0].roomNumber%>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Resident 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="resident1" value="<%=communityMapData[0].resident1%>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Resident 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="resident2" value="<%=communityMapData[0].resident2%>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Room standing in community:</label><br>
            <select name="roomColorID" value="<%=communityMapData[0].roomColorID%>">
                <option value='g'>Good Standing - Green</option>
                <option value='y'>Okay Standing - Yellow</option>
                <option value='r'>Bad Standing - Red</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Are there any potential student leaders in this room?</label><br>
            <select name="leaderInRoom" value="<%=communityMapData[0].leaderInRoom%>">
                <option value=1>Yes</option>
                <option value=0>No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Do you tend to visit this room often?</label><br>
            <select name="visitMost" value="<%=communityMapData[0].visitMost%>">
                <option value=1>Yes</option>
                <option value=0>No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Are there residents in this room that you do not see often?</label><br>
            <select name="notSeen" value="<%=communityMapData[0].notSeen%>">
                <option value=1>Yes</option>
                <option value=0>No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Please indicate the rooms this room connects with often as well as at least one new fact and interaction with each resident of this room.</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="factsAndInteractions" value="<%=communityMapData[0].factsAndInteractions%>">
        </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure where I'm supposed to fill in the value for the select form identifiers, so any help or tips would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such attribute called 'value' for the `select` tag, you need to specify it in `option` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `for` loop in your EJS file like so

```
<select id="select" name="name">
    <% for(var a=0; a < itemList.length; a++) { %>
     <option value="<%= itemList[a].id %>"><%= itemList[a].info %></option>
    <% } %>
</select>
```

Then once you submit your form you can access selected value using `name`